# Does all classes need to have getters and setters? Is there some classes that may not necessarily need the usage of getters or setters?

Tags: java, class, stack, getter, setter

E.g. Implementing a stack class or a queue class,

I can only think of getter methods. Will that be okay? Or do I really need to find setter methods for those classes?

Comment: Look at the libraries that come with the JDK. Lots of them don’t need getters and setters.

Comment: I no longer remember the title, sorry. A colleague had a book basically claiming that the mere presence of getters and setters were a sign that you were not doing proper object-oriented design and programming. According to this book you should prefer *not* to have them.

Comment: Oh, hmm I see! Thank you for the comments I'll take note of those :)

Comment: @OleV.V.: maybe that was Allen Holub?

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks for suggesting. It doesn’t immediately ring a bell, so not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and Setters are not mandatory, they are primarily used with public classes that contain private fields.
If your stack/Queue class needs methods such as push(),pop(),drop(),etc., you don't need getters and setter for your use case.

Example: push() is a custom setter method.
pop() is a custom getter method.